# Is Tile same as Layer?

Tags: tiles, overlay, arcgis-api-wpf

Is there difference between a tile server or a layer server?
Can I load tile in ArcGIS control in WPF from some other source?
Can I host my own layer server? Or is there any such thing as layer server?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question.  Please [edit] this one to focus on whichever one its only answer is addressing so as not to invalidate that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not positive, but I think you mean dynamic or tiled map services?  The difference here is the speed with which a web application will work.  Tiled services are cached at different levels - meaning a bunch of tiles are created at each level to improve speed.  Dynamic services have no cache levels and take longer to load.  You would need to use a dynamic service if your data is going to be editted often or is going to have its symbology changed.

ESRI documentation on cahcing map services (tiles):
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_map_caching/005300000059000000/